# CMS for appoitment-like site

Tags: cms, recommendations, widgets

i need to quickly create a web site for a hairdresser person.
Main feature is to let his potential clients to reserve time for service.

I've never had to deal with any CMS, because i'm developing sites from scratch.

What the CMS do you recommend for my case, which has necessary extensions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read our FAQ, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq.  This question is no appropriate for Webmasters.

Answer (score 2):

[Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) can do the job, and will probably easier on you than anything else as it has a good UI, [it's own stack site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for support, a well written [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) and [searchable plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/).

You can buy high quality themes from [theme forest](http://www.themeforest.com) and there are a number of [reservation system plugins available](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/reservation-system). Added together you should be able to get a site together in under two days.

If these plugins don't meet your needs hotscripts have a number of free or paid for [booking systems available](http://www.hotscripts.com/search/php/booking+system) which have varying degrees of complexity - everything from ticketing systems to hotel reservations.

Comment: And don't forget that if you are looking for help on WP it has it's own SE -http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @VincePettit I did provide a link to that...